# Bootstrap Image Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Does anyone know how to do this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) from w3schools but with 3 thumbnails

This is my code so far:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 ">

      <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
      <div class="polaroid">
        <img id="myImg" src="home-page-feature-thumbnail-image-front-featured-films-slider-2.jpg" alt="Caption1" width="auto;" height="auto;">

        <div class="info">
          <p style="color:#971604; font-weight:bold;">This is a text.</p>
          <h4>Caption 1</h4>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- The Modal -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- The Close Button -->
        <span class="close" >×</span>


        <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01" src="img.jpg">

        <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
        <div id="caption"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">

      <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
      <div class="polaroid">
        <img id="myImg2" src="home-page-feature-thumbnail-image-front-featured-films-slider-4.jpg" alt="Caption2" width="auto;" height="auto;">
        <div class="info">
          <p style="color:#971604; font-weight:bold;">This is another text.</p>
          <h4>Caption 2</h4>
        </div>

      </div

      <!-- The Modal -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- The Close Button -->
        <span class="close" >×</span>

        <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
        <img class="modal-content" id="img02" src="img2.jpg">

        <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
        <div id="caption"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
       <div class="polaroid">
        <img id="myImg" src="home-page-feature-thumbnail-image-front-featured-films-slider-2.jpg" alt="Caption3" width="auto;" height="auto">

        <div class="info">
          <p style="color:#971604; font-weight:bold;">This is the 3rd text.</p>
          <h4>Caption 3</h4>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- The Modal -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- The Close Button -->
        <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

        <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
        <img class="modal-content" id="img03" src="img3.jpg">

        <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
        <div id="caption"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

and this is what I have for my javascript

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
   modal.style.display = "block";
   modalImg.src = this.src;
   captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

this is whats in my css file:

```
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */

div.polaroid {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

div.info {
 padding: 10px 20px;
} 

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

 /* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
 }

 /* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
 #caption {
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
   width: 80%;
   max-width: 700px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #ccc;
   padding: 10px 0;
   height: 150px;
 }

  /* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
  .modal-content, #caption { 
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
   }

  @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
  }

  @keyframes zoom {
     from {transform:scale(0)} 
     to {transform:scale(1)}
  }

  /* The Close Button */
  .close {
     position: absolute;
     top: 35px;
     right: 25px;
     color: #ffffff;
     font-size: 150px;
     transition: 0.3s;


     }

     .close:hover,
     .close:focus {
         color: #bbb;
         text-decoration: none;
         cursor: pointer;
     }

     /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
     @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
        .modal-content {
            width: 100%;
         }
     }
```

It's all working fine for the first image but for the other two images, no modal is appearing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add modal for each and every image , Just one Modal is enough. 
In your code modal is working for only first image because your js code is handling only first image. Find below code that works for three images.

```js
 function  handleImageClick(c){
   var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
   var modalImg = document.getElementById("modalImage");
   var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = c.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = c.alt;
}
```

```css
div.polaroid {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

div.info {
 padding: 10px 20px;
} 

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

 /* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
 }

 /* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
 #caption {
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
   width: 80%;
   max-width: 700px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #ccc;
   padding: 10px 0;
   height: 150px;
 }

  /* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
  .modal-content, #caption { 
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
   }

  @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
  }

  @keyframes zoom {
     from {transform:scale(0)} 
     to {transform:scale(1)}
  }

  /* The Close Button */
  .close {
     position: absolute;
     top: 35px;
     right: 25px;
     color: #ffffff;
     font-size: 150px;
     transition: 0.3s;


     }

     .close:hover,
     .close:focus {
         color: #bbb;
         text-decoration: none;
         cursor: pointer;
     }

     /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
     @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
        .modal-content {
            width: 100%;
         }
     }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
   <div class="polaroid">
    <img id="myImg"   onClick="handleImageClick(this);" src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Caption1" width="auto;" height="auto;">
    <div class="info">
     <p style="color:#971604; font-weight:bold;">This is a text.</p>
     <h4>Caption 1</h4>
    </div>
   </div>
     </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="polaroid">
   <img id="myImg2"  onClick="handleImageClick(this);"  src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Caption2" width="auto;" height="auto;">
   <div class="info">
    <p style="color:#971604; font-weight:bold;">This is another text.</p>
    <h4>Caption 2</h4>
   </div>
  </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="polaroid">
        <img id="myImg"   onClick="handleImageClick(this);" src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Caption3" width="auto;" height="auto">

        <div class="info">
          <p style="color:#971604; font-weight:bold;">This is the 3rd text.</p>
          <h4>Caption 3</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <!-- The Close Button -->
        <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

        <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
        <img class="modal-content" id="modalImage" src="">

        <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
        <div id="caption"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: btw how do i do it so that when i click to the photo, it's not the image in the thumbnail that is show but a different image. Like in the example, in the thumbnail it's a nature photo but how do i do it so when i click it, a photo of trees appear? something like this? thank you!

Comment: Do you want to show same image like image of tree or different images every time ?

Comment: different images for each thumbnail. So eg something like this:
Thumbnail 1: nature (when clicked: photo of tree)
Thumbnail 2: cats (when clicked: photo of dogs)
Thumbnail 3: houses (when clicked photo of people)

something like this? would it be possible? Thank you so much!

Comment: of course it is possible . There are lots of way you can achieve this . one of them is you can put one more hidden image just below each thumbnail image element and when  user click on thumbnail then we are passing current element in handleImageClick function  and you are getting c.src and c.alt for current thumbnail  , here instead of c.src and c.alt you can get next hidden sibling element using c.nextElementSibling.src and c.nextElementSibling.alt. This may not be the best way. Best way depend on your actual requirement.

Comment: can you please help me code this? if its not too much hassle! thank you so much! the one in my original code, i did have a hidden image right?